# Play JSON: Reading and validating a JsObject with unknown keys

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm reading a nested JSON document using several `Reads[T]` implementations, however, I'm stuck with the following sub-object:

```
{
    ...,
    "attributes": {
        "keyA": [1.68, 5.47, 3.57],
        "KeyB": [true],
        "keyC": ["Lorem", "Ipsum"]
     },
     ...
}
```

The keys ("keyA", "keyB"...) as well as the amount of keys are not known at compile time and can vary. The values of the keys are always `JsArray` instances, but of  different size and type (however, all elements of a particular array must have the *same* `JsValue` type).

The Scala representation of one single attribute:

```
case class Attribute[A](name: String, values: Seq[A])
// 'A' can only be String, Boolean or Double
```

The goal is to create a `Reads[Seq[Attribute]`] that can be used for the "attributes"-field when transforming the whole document (remember, "attributes" is just a sub-document).

Then there is a simple map that contains allowed combinations of keys and array types that should be used to validate attributes. Edit: This map is **specific for each request** (or rather specific for every type of json document). But you can assume that it is always available in the scope.

```
val required = Map(
  "KeyA" -> "Double",
  "KeyB" -> "String",
  "KeyD" -> "String",
)
```

So in the case of the JSON shown above, the `Reads` should create two errors:

1. "keyB" does exist, but has the wrong type (expected String, was boolean).
2. "keyD" is missing (whereas keyC is not needed and can be ignored).

---

I'm having trouble creating the necessary `Reads`. The first thing I tried as a first step, from the perspective of the outer `Reads`:

```
...
(__ \ "attributes").reads[Map[String, JsArray]]...
...
```

I thought this is a nice first step because if the JSON structure is not an object containing `String`s and `JsArray`s as key-value pairs, then the `Reads` fails with proper error messages. It works, but: I don't know how to go on from there. Of course I just could create a method that transforms the `Map` into a `Seq[Attribute]`, but this method somehow should return a `JsResult`, since there are further validations to do.

The second thing I tried:

```
  val attributeSeqReads = new Reads[Seq[Attribute]] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = json match {
      case JsObject(fields) => processAttributes(fields)
      case _ => JsError("attributes not an object")
    }
    def processAttributes(fields: Map[String, JsValue]): JsResult[Seq[Attribute]] = {
      // ...
    }
  }
```

The idea was to validate each element of the map manually within `processAttributes`. But I think this is too complicated. Any help is appreciated.

**edit for clarification:**

At the beginning of the post I said that the keys (keyA, keyB...) are unknown at compile time. Later on I said that those keys are part of the map `required` which is used for validation. This sounds like a contradiction, but the thing is: `required` is *specific for each document/request* and is also not known at compile time. But you don't need to worry about that, just assume that for every request the correct `required` is already available in the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are too confused by the task

> The keys ("keyA", "keyB"...) as well as the amount of keys are not known at compile time and can vary

So the number of keys and their types are known in advance and the final?

> So in the case of the JSON shown above, the Reads should create two
>   errors:
>
> 1. "keyB" does exist, but has the wrong type (expected String, was
>      boolean).
> 2. "keyD" is missing (whereas keyC is not needed and can be ignored).

Your main task is just to check the availability and compliance?

You may implement `Reads[Attribute]` for every your key with `Reads.list(Reads.of[A])` (this Reads will check type and required)  and skip omitted (if not required) with `Reads.pure(Attribute[A])`. Then tuple convert to list (`_.productIterator.toList`) and you will get `Seq[Attribute]`

```
val r = (
  (__ \ "attributes" \ "keyA").read[Attribute[Double]](list(of[Double]).map(Attribute("keyA", _))) and
    (__ \ "attributes" \ "keyB").read[Attribute[Boolean]](list(of[Boolean]).map(Attribute("keyB", _))) and
    ((__ \ "attributes" \ "keyC").read[Attribute[String]](list(of[String]).map(Attribute("keyC", _))) or Reads.pure(Attribute[String]("keyC", List()))) and 
    (__ \ "attributes" \ "keyD").read[Attribute[String]](list(of[String]).map(Attribute("keyD", _)))        
  ).tupled.map(_.productIterator.toList)

scala>json1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"attributes":{"keyA":[1.68,5.47,3.57],"keyB":[true],"keyD":["Lorem","Ipsum"]}}

scala>res37: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[List[Any]] = JsSuccess(List(Attribute(keyA,List(1.68, 5.47, 3.57)), Attribute(KeyB,List(true)), Attribute(keyC,List()), Attribute(KeyD,List(Lorem, Ipsum))),)   

scala>json2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"attributes":{"keyA":[1.68,5.47,3.57],"keyB":[true],"keyC":["Lorem","Ipsum"]}}    

scala>res38: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[List[Any]] = JsError(List((/attributes/keyD,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray())))))    

scala>json3: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"attributes":{"keyA":[1.68,5.47,3.57],"keyB":["Lorem"],"keyC":["Lorem","Ipsum"]}}    

scala>res42: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[List[Any]] = JsError(List((/attributes/keyD,List(ValidationError(List(error.path.missing),WrappedArray()))), (/attributes/keyB(0),List(ValidationError(List(error.expected.jsboolean),WrappedArray())))))
```

If you will have more than 22 attributes, you will have another problem: Tuple with more than 22 properties.

**for dynamic properties in runtime**

inspired by 'Reads.traversableReads[F[_], A]'

```
def attributesReads(required: Map[String, String]) = Reads {json =>
  type Errors = Seq[(JsPath, Seq[ValidationError])]

  def locate(e: Errors, idx: Int) = e.map { case (p, valerr) => (JsPath(idx)) ++ p -> valerr }

  required.map{
    case (key, "Double") => (__ \  key).read[Attribute[Double]](list(of[Double]).map(Attribute(key, _))).reads(json)
    case (key, "String") => (__ \ key).read[Attribute[String]](list(of[String]).map(Attribute(key, _))).reads(json)
    case (key, "Boolean") => (__ \ key).read[Attribute[Boolean]](list(of[Boolean]).map(Attribute(key, _))).reads(json)
    case _ => JsError("")
  }.iterator.zipWithIndex.foldLeft(Right(Vector.empty): Either[Errors, Vector[Attribute[_ >: Double with String with Boolean]]]) {
      case (Right(vs), (JsSuccess(v, _), _)) => Right(vs :+ v)
      case (Right(_), (JsError(e), idx)) => Left(locate(e, idx))
      case (Left(e), (_: JsSuccess[_], _)) => Left(e)
      case (Left(e1), (JsError(e2), idx)) => Left(e1 ++ locate(e2, idx))
    }
  .fold(JsError.apply, { res =>
    JsSuccess(res.toList)
  })
}

(__ \ "attributes").read(attributesReads(Map("keyA" -> "Double"))).reads(json)

scala> json: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"attributes":{"keyA":[1.68,5.47,3.57],"keyB":[true],"keyD":["Lorem","Ipsum"]}}

scala> res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[List[Attribute[_ >: Double with String with Boolean]]] = JsSuccess(List(Attribute(keyA,List(1.68, 5.47, 3.57))),/attributes)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I edited my post. The allowed keys are specific for every json document. Request A may contain attributes that are related to cars (weight, horsepower, color) while request B could contain attributes related to countries (name, flag, president, population...). The map `required` that I used above for validation is loaded specifically for every type of document. So both the keys as well as the validation information is not known at compile thime, but at runtime, I know which attributes are allowed for a specific type of json dosument.

Comment: ok. How do you implement key -> type for "not required" properties?

Comment: You mean optional attributes? Not needed at the moment. Everything in `required` has to be part of the incoming json. If the json contains additional attribute keys that are not needed, they just get ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Andrey. I'm busy atm but I will look into it within the next days.

Comment: If I answer your question, please mark as answered.

Comment: Couldn't have a look at it until today, sorry. I tested it with several json-inputs and it seems to work nicely, thanks.